# Passing environment variables to docker from GitLab CI/CD job failing

Tags: dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I am having issues passing variables which are defined in the GitLab ci file to my docker file
My GitLab CI file looks like this

```
variables:
  IMAGE             : "openjdk"
  IMAGE_TAG         : "11-slim"

docker-image:
  extends: .build
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION  : ${JDK_IMAGE}:${JDK_IMAGE_TAG}
```

My Docker file looks a bit like this:

```
# --- STAGE 1 ----------------------------------------------------------------
# Getting ARGS for build
ARG DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION

# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM ${DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION} as build
```

Now i am getting the following error when the pipeline starts the docker build:

```
Step 1/7 : ARG DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION
Step 2/7 : FROM ${DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION} as build
base name (${DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION}) should not be blank
```

Can someone help point me where i am going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### consider defining global ARG's and override it when you build.
example

ARG sample_TAG=test
ARG sample_TAG
WORKDIR /opt/sample-test
RUN echo "image tag is ${sample_TAG}"
FROM $sample_TAG
VOLUME /opt
RUN mkdir /opt/sample-test